# AC vs DC voltage regulator for hybrid drone

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, generator, drone

[image: Weight][image: Current Idea]I am working on building a hybrid power source for a drone. I have a 7 HP, 2-stroke, 2 kg engine tied to a 7000 W permanent-magnet motor (1.8 kg, not sure a truck alternator could be close to that), which will generate 3-phase AC power.

I hope to get about 4000 W from the generator at about 50 VAC. I will have a 12s Samsung 21700 40t lithium battery pack at max. 4.1 V per cell in parallel with the generator after a 3-phase rectifier. The battery pack will smooth out the generator power, provide peak power when needed, and backup power if the engine dies.

The battery needs to be protected from any possible overvoltage or surges while the generator charges it, as the motor speed may vary quite a bit.

My question is: is it easier to individually regulate each leg of the 3-phase AC power before it goes into a rectifier, or to regulate the DC voltage coming out of the rectifier? I need a relatively clean, fixed 50 VDC for inputs into the drone motor controllers.

The weight of any voltage controller is obviously an issue, so large transformers are probably out. I also need the ability to handle about 100 A.

Comment: DC. I challenge you to find a way to do it on the AC side, not that they don't exist. But you will probably need to dig a bit for them. But why does your wording make it sound like you are not using a charger? Use a charger. Add a bypass for the charger and battery if you must to allow the generator to directly provide power to the load while the battery is charging, but definitely do not just feed voltage, even regulated voltage, directly to the battery,

Comment: Did you consider using an alternator with a field winding as a power source instead of a permanent magnet synchronous motor? I think the control will be easier that way, especially if you really need to run at a variety of different speeds. Also, your life will be much easier if you always run the ICE at the same speed.

Comment: Why not just feed regulated voltage to the battery? I will be using a voltage monitor to measure each cell, but no BMS, on purpose. I thought about using a charger, but I want the battery bank to also smooth out generator ripples to the motors, and a charger seems to negate that. Will put ideal diodes in between battery and generator to prevent reverse current to generator. My 7 kw generator weighs 2 kg, I think an alternator with field winding would weigh much more.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a chart showing the main components of your intended build, along with specifications including weight and cost. That would make it easier for us to target each component with possible alternatives. Also a flow chart or diagram showing how each component is interconnected.

Comment: I have had second thoughts about the low efficiency of a simple 3phase rectifier. It won't work with the extremely high power density specs and efficiency implied not specified in the question.  It is necessary to derate magnetic power density for high peak/average operation.which occurs with direct connection. Thus it becomes necessary to have a resitive load or PFC output using a switched inductor rectfier. i.e. a MOSFET bridge with active PFC then a DC-DC charger. There is no simpler method when optimal efficiency and optimal specific power (density) are necessary.  Sorry.

Comment: Car alternators are heavy because they are very inefficient with the pulsed currents that occur. For example if the average current is 50A and battery ripple voltage is 5% then the peak current is 1000A for 5% duration.. ir if 10% voltage ripple is 500A pk for 10% duration. Although the pulse is not exactly square, this pulsation forces derating the power specs to the peak current to prevent saturation.  So you must search for high specific power, and high efficiency 3phase chargers compatible with your generator and battery voltages and currents. Think of a 7kW Tesla charger. That may kill it

Comment: An electronic speed controller which supports regen braking could be an option instead of a diode bridge. If you command the torque intelligently, you can implement battery charge control, mechanical torque limiting, etc, and extract the maximum power available within the applicable limits. The speed controller can convert mechanical energy to electrical energy and charge the batteries with DC at almost any speed above idle (subject to power limits imposed by physics).

Comment: Thank you all for the detailed suggestions. I am an aerospace engineer, not electrical, so my circuit ideas may be hairbrained. I posted images of my current plan, and weight breakdown. Please critique and find any major flaws I may have made

Comment: I foresee issues with the use of series diodes. Get ones rated for the full voltage instead.

Comment: Very hard to find diodes capable of say 50v reverse, plus able to handle 100 amps. That is why I went with the series diodes. They aren't really diodes, but MOSFET circuits acting as ideal diodes

Comment: That’s even worse. They won’t switch simultaneously, so for a brief moment, one of them will take the full voltage and probably let out its magic smoke. I find are 123 different ones to choose from, all in stock on Digi-Key. Also, at 100 V, you can make use of Schottky diodes positive tempco and simply parallel them. Same for MOSFETs if you need active rectification.

Answer (score 8):

The answer to your question is that regulating DC is much easier than regulating AC. But I also want to comment on a few things.

First, you mention that your gas engine speed will vary a lot. Why is that? If the only purpose of the gas engine is to charge the battery, you should probably not vary the speed too much.

Second, you say that your gas engine is rated at 7 HP. That is 5220 Watts of mechanical output power. You are hoping to get 4000 Watts of electrical power out of the permanent magnet machine (motor/generator). 4000 Watts / 5220 Watts = 77 percent efficiency. That seems realistic, so that is good.

You say you are going to use a permanent magnet motor with a three phase rectifier. This topology can work, HOWEVER, in this particular setup where you have a gasoline engine driving a permanent magnet synchronous generator followed by a bridge rectifier, followed by a battery, the only way to regulate the output voltage of the generator is to change the speed of the engine. If the engine is not running fast enough, the battery won't charge at all. If it runs just a little bit too fast, the charge current (and load on the engine) will increase dramatically. With this type of setup, you have to be able to vary the speed of the engine to control charging.

Related to this is the problem that the gasoline engine will put out peak horsepower at exactly ONE speed, usually the maximum speed. So your mechanical power will be 7 HP only when the gas engine is at max speed. At lower speeds it will not be rated for 7 HP. It may or may not be capable of supplying 7 HP at lower speeds, but if it can at all it will be over-loaded. And if it can't, it may stall the engine.

Probably the simplest solution to this is to do what Tony proposed, using an alternator with a field winding instead of a 3 phase permanent magnet motor. In this type of generator, you control the output by regulating the field winding. It can maintain constant output across a wider range of speeds. The engine speed would not need to vary, necessarily, or you could operate it at whatever speed produces the highest efficiency or highest power as needed. This is how alternators on automotive and marine engines typically work.

Another option here would be to keep the permanent magnet machine and replace the bridge rectifier with an electronic motor controller that is capable of regenerative braking. Regenerative braking is a way of running the motor as a generator to charge the battery pack. Electronic control is required. In this mode of operation, battery charge current can be regulated over a wide range of speeds of the gas engine. This is quite a bit more complex than the simple bridge rectifier scheme. But by programming the electronic controller, you can pretty much get the battery charger to do whatever you want.

Coupling a generator to small gas engine can have some unexpected problems. A friend of mine worked on a project like that. The engine output torque is not smooth at all. It comes in pulses when the piston or pistons fire. There tends to be a lot of vibration which can wreak havoc with bearings and whatnot. This could lead to shortened lifespan of your 7kW motor/generator if it is not designed for this sort of thing. Couplings which seem strong enough based on static torque analysis may fail in practice.

It definitely sounds like a cool project, but like most projects which are worthwhile, you are probably going to have some failures along the way which will cause you to revise your plans as you move forward to the ultimate goal.

Comment: I expect my engine RPM to vary a lot just because there isn't much inertia because the engine only weighs 2 kg. I don't have a flywheel. I do intend to try to keep engine spinning at the max torque rpm. I also mentioned I expect 4kw not 5, closer to your efficiency value. I do have a belt between engine, and generator to lessen vibration, and engine is 2 stroke so smaller, more frequent torque pulses than a 4 stroke. Engine mounted on sorbothane

Comment: @GregSorter Why would it vary, if you do not vary it?

Comment: @GregSorter Engines mass is a flywheel in and of itself. Are you sure this is even a concern? Maybe our definitions of "vary a lot" is different. When you say that I imagine >25% but that seems unlikely for an engine without a wildly varying mechanical load.

Comment: I would think the load from the generator varies greatly depending on power requirements from manuevering. I will have 4 motors, each at 1 kw running propellers, so possibility for huge power swings exists.   don't have it running yet so cannot experimentally verify, but I expect load to be all over the place

Comment: The electrical load will be all over the place but the battery should smooth it out. The electrical load on the alternator and the mechanical load on the engine can be kept smooth because of the battery, depending on how the control system works.

Comment: The confusing thing for me was the fact that 3 phase 50 volts AC going into a diode rectifier will lead to 50*1.707  volts DC coming out. My initial calculations didn't take that into account, so I needed add a pulley and belt to the system to lower the generator speed by 40% vs the engine RPM

Comment: you need a high RPM flywheel. and it may not fly with a DCDC converter

Comment: If you use a DC-DC, you will have to add some big inductor. If you use a motor controller you can use the inductance of the motor windings as your DC-DC converter inductor. If you ARENT going to use the three-phase bridge topology and you aren't going to use an alternator with a controllable field, then you should use a motor controller that can do regenerative braking. Your concern about the back EMF being too large shouldn't be a problem. You can link the shafts directly and the controller will keep the shaft torque and battery current under control at all RPMs.

Answer (score 1):

Something perhaps not considered about an alternator is that it is designed to be able to put out about 15 volts to charge a 12V battery at idle speed, about 600 RPM for the ICE, and the pulley ratio makes the alternator shaft speed about 2400 RPM. I found a [30A Nippon Denso alternator](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XDHCKJC) that weighs just 7 pounds (3.2 kg). That is 450 watts. At max engine speed, 6000 RPM, however, this same alternator can produce 30A at 150V, or 4500 watts, with shaft speed of 24,000 RPM. A custom designed alternator with premium components should be able to get even more.

The ICE should always run at its most efficient speed, so with this particular automotive alternator you would need to be able to convert this 150 VDC to your nominal 50 VDC for the battery pack. An ordinary off-the-shelf 120 VAC to 48 VDC switching supply will also work on 100-200 VDC, and once the battery pack is somewhat depleted, there will always be room for additional charge, so something like a MPPT controller will be ideal.

You might also look into small high-efficiency diesel engines, such as [this](https://news.mit.edu/2014/liquidpiston-small-efficient-rotary-engine-1205). It weighs 4 pounds and output is 3.5 HP (2.6 kW) at 10,000 RPM, and they expect to have a 3 pound version that outputs 5 HP (3.7 kW) at 15,000 RPM.

Model aircraft engines may give you the power/weight specifications you need, although some can be pricey. [Here](https://www.chiefaircraft.com/radio-control/turbine-gas-glow-engines/dle/dle-35ra.html) is one weighing about 2 pounds that delivers about 4 HP at 8500 RPM (for $400!).

Comment: My 7 hp engine cost about $700, and weighs 2 KG. That seems to be the sweet spot for weight/power ratio